# Bootstrap 4 carousel space to right

Tags: css, responsive-design, slider, carousel, bootstrap-4

I have an issue with Bootstrap 4 carousel space to right, which does not align well to page. Example Here: http://jsbin.com/wakuyiqebu It is much more noticeable on mobile.

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5 bg-dark">
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7 padding-off">    
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-
        ...
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this problem goes away, at least in my browser, when I remove the "padding-off" from your section tag.

Comment: That did not work. There is still space to the right of the main container.